# Nextcord slash commands voice channel

Tags: nextcord

how can I select a voice channel with a slash command just [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCwQi.png)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nextcord 2.1.0+, you can annotate an option with `nextcord.VoiceChannel`:

```
from nextcord import Interaction, VoiceChannel

@bot.slash_command()
async def voice(interaction: Interaction, channel: VoiceChannel):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"You said: {channel}")
```

Prior to 2.1.0, the only way was to annotate an option with `nextcord.abc.GuildChannel` and specify a list of channel types:

```
from nextcord import ChannelType, Interaction
from nextcord.abc import GuildChannel

@bot.slash_command()
async def voice(
    interaction: Interaction,
    channel: GuildChannel = SlashOption(channel_types=[ChannelType.voice])
):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"You said: {channel}")
```